# Unexpected argument error in sns.kdeplot()

Tags: python, arguments, seaborn

I'm working in a project in which I need to create a KDE plot. Here's my code:

`sns.kdeplot(x = 'total_attempts', hue = 'status', fill = True, data = toplot)`

Where `toplot` is a `pd.DataFrame` with two columns, `total_attempts` (integer) and `status` (boolean).

However, I receive the following error:

`_bivariate_kdeplot() got multiple values for argument 'x'`

This error normally comes when a both a positional and a keyword argument are specified in the calling of the function. But I don't see that this is the case in my code.

Any idea on why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: You need seaborn >= 0.11. What version of seaborn are you using?

Comment: Got it, I was using 0.10.1. Just upgraded to 0.11.1 and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3279716/alex) pointed out in the comments, upgrading seaborn >= 0.11 fixed the problem.